# How to apply random sampling using multiple criteria's for selection in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

In my datasets, I have the ID, gender, village and crop area in hectare from different farmers.

I have to create a group of 5 hectares farmers for one group using crop area. In each group four farmers will be selected randomly, but minimum 25% of women farmers crop area has to be selected in each group randomly.

I am trying to find out how, but I am stuck in getting the correct solution.

Here is my dummy data set:

```
    Farmer_id Gender Village  Crop_area
0           1      F  Nashik       1.00
1           2      F  Nashik       0.50
2           3      M  Nashik       1.00
3           4      M  Nashik       0.80
4           5      M  Nashik       0.60
5           6      M  Nashik       0.10
6           7      M  Nashik       1.00
7           8      F  Nashik       0.60
8           9      F  Nashik       1.00
9          10      F  Nashik       0.29
10         11      M  Nashik       0.70
11         12      M  Nashik       1.00
12         13      M  Nashik       0.41
13         14      M  Nashik       1.00
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
df['Crop_Area_Cum'] = df['Crop_area'].cumsum()
grouped = df.groupby(df.Gender)
df_male = grouped.get_group("M")
df_female = grouped.get_group("F")
df['Sample']=4
df['Selected Farmers'] = df['Sample'].apply(np.ceil).astype(int)
df['Selected Farmers'] = df.groupby('Gender').apply(lambda df: df['Village'].sample(df['Selected Farmers'].iat[0])).reset_index(level=0)['Village']
df['Selected Farmers'] = df['Selected Farmers'].fillna('')

    Farmer_id Gender        ...        Sample  Selected Farmers
0           1      F        ...             4            Nashik
1           2      F        ...             4            Nashik
2           3      M        ...             4                  
3           4      M        ...             4                  
4           5      M        ...             4                  
5           6      M        ...             4            Nashik
6           7      M        ...             4            Nashik
7           8      F        ...             4            Nashik
8           9      F        ...             4            Nashik
9          10      F        ...             4                  
10         11      M        ...             4                  
11         12      M        ...             4                  
12         13      M        ...             4            Nashik
13         14      M        ...             4            Nashik
```

The output is not correct, because none of the criteria is followed for sampling.

Actual output required:
[image]

Comment: @notarobot, Sum of the Crop_area column is 5 (cumsum), area of the crop

Comment: I don't understand "5 hectares farmers". From the required output, I assume the combined area in one group should be 5 hectars. In your example it is exactly 5 hectars for both groups. What happens, if the numbers don't align? I guess the size must be *at least* 5 hectars.

Comment: What happens if not enough women are within a group of "5 hectars farmers"? Should the group be extended (leading to larger areas)?

Comment: @KnutKiesel, Yes, Combined Area in One Group should be at least 5 hectares, if some case group for area is 4.9, 4.6,5.04, it will be rounding to 5.

Comment: @KnutKiesel,if not enough women are within a group of 5 hectares, i.e  only 10% women area in dataset, and we required 30% women area (i.e 1.5 Hectare area) in such case male farmers will be select for remaining area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first idea is to assign a random group number to each row.  then sum that up to see if each area is close to 5.  Keep doing that until that condition is true.  Then random selection flags are assigned to each row such that each group has 4 Trues and the rest Falses.

Then next step is to keep assigning those random selection flags until the female(s) selected represent at least 25% of the total female land ownership. Keep running the code until a solution is achieved.

```
nb_groups = 2
min_acceptable_female_prp = 0.25
```

The random selector function:

```
def rnd_sel(x):
    arr = [True]*4+[False]*(len(x)-4)
    np.random.shuffle(arr)
    return arr
```

The main processing loop:

```
for i in range(100):
    dfg = df.assign(Group=random.choices(range(1,nb_groups+1), k=len(df)))

    if (dfg.groupby('Group').sum()['Crop_area']-5).abs().max() < 0.5:
        dfg.sort_values(['Group','Gender'], inplace=True)

        print(f'\nGroup area solve iteration: {i}\n')
        dfg_s = dfg.groupby(['Group','Gender']).sum()
        dfg_s['Tot_Grp_Crop_area'] = dfg_s.groupby('Group')['Crop_area'].transform(sum)
        print(dfg_s)    
        
        # make sure females are present in each group
        if len(dfg_s.loc[pd.IndexSlice[:, 'F'], :]) == nb_groups:
            dfg['Selected'] = dfg.groupby('Group')['Group'].transform(rnd_sel)
            
            print()
            print(dfg)
            
            dfg_sf = dfg[dfg['Selected']].groupby(['Group','Gender']).sum()  
            print(dfg_sf)
            
            if len(dfg_sf.loc[pd.IndexSlice[:, 'F'], :]) == nb_groups:
                dfg_s['Gender_Selected_area'] = dfg_sf['Crop_area']
                
                dfg_s['Gender_Selected_area_prp'] = dfg_s['Gender_Selected_area']/dfg_s['Crop_area']
                print(dfg_s)
                
                min_female_prp = dfg_s.loc[pd.IndexSlice[:, 'F'], :]['Gender_Selected_area_prp'].min()  
                
                if min_female_prp >= min_acceptable_female_prp:
                    print(f'\nSolution achieved with minimum female crop area representation of {min_female_prp*100:.1f}%')
                else:
                    print('*** solution not achieved')
    
    break
```

Associated output:

```
Group area solve iteration: 0

              Farmer_id  Crop_area  Tot_Grp_Crop_area
Group Gender                                         
1     F              11       2.10               5.41
      M              38       3.31               5.41
2     F              19       1.29               4.59
      M              37       3.30               4.59

    Farmer_id Gender Village  Crop_area  Group  Selected
0           1      F  Nashik       1.00      1     False
1           2      F  Nashik       0.50      1      True
7           8      F  Nashik       0.60      1      True
2           3      M  Nashik       1.00      1      True
3           4      M  Nashik       0.80      1      True
5           6      M  Nashik       0.10      1     False
11         12      M  Nashik       1.00      1     False
12         13      M  Nashik       0.41      1     False
8           9      F  Nashik       1.00      2      True
9          10      F  Nashik       0.29      2     False
4           5      M  Nashik       0.60      2      True
6           7      M  Nashik       1.00      2     False
10         11      M  Nashik       0.70      2      True
13         14      M  Nashik       1.00      2      True
              Farmer_id  Crop_area  Selected
Group Gender                                
1     F              10        1.1         2
      M               7        1.8         2
2     F               9        1.0         1
      M              30        2.3         3
              Farmer_id  Crop_area  Tot_Grp_Crop_area  Gender_Selected_area  \
Group Gender                                                                  
1     F              11       2.10               5.41                   1.1   
      M              38       3.31               5.41                   1.8   
2     F              19       1.29               4.59                   1.0   
      M              37       3.30               4.59                   2.3   

              Gender_Selected_area_prp  
Group Gender                            
1     F                       0.523810  
      M                       0.543807  
2     F                       0.775194  
      M                       0.696970  

Solution achieved with minimum female crop area representation of 52.4%
```

Comment: in my output of the above code show me 1 iteration, Group 1 (Male and Female) and in Group 2 (Only Male) selected randomly. Thanks this ideas help me for selection of groups for 5 hectares and selection of 4 farmers.

Comment: @Kiran Yes - what you received as output does not surprise me.  You would need to iterate on that portion of the code until you receive females selected that meet your criteria.  Let me know if you are interested in further refinements by me when I get more time.

Comment: sure, Really interested because in each group there need 25% female farmers, and then the group is successfully created. I tried but not found any correct solution.

Comment: @Kiran  Is it simply at least 25% female farmers - which would be at least 1 out of 4?  Or is it that a female has to be selected that represents at least 25% of the total female crop area for that group?  Or something else?

Comment: 25% of the total female crop area for that group.

Answer (score 2):

There's more than one way to tackle this.

[Rejection Sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rejection_sampling) is perhaps the simplest.

Your new function wishes to return a suitable 4-tuple of farmers.

1. Create an empty `set()`.
2. While length of set < 4:

   - Keep [choosing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randint) a random id, and add it to the set.
3. Now you have 4 candidate farmers. Compute summary statistics on gender and area.
4. Decide whether these four are acceptable or should be rejected. Either `return` the four, or start from scratch at step (1.)